# Is it disruptive to run two installations of SharePoint on two servers in the same AD domain?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, domain

I'm a developer evaluating the BI capabilities of SharePoint. We've already got a SharePoint server running in our domain, but enabling the needed functionality would require a lot of work from our SharePoint administrators, so I thought I'd run it in a virtual machine on my local computer.

During the SharePoint installation, I realized that the server running SharePoint needs to be connected to an AD domain. My question is: would this be okay or would it in any way disrupt the existing SharePoint instance? They would share no common data, be on different servers, only thing shared would be the domain they're connected to.

On my VM I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 and SharePoint 2013.

Comment: It should not cause any problems

Comment: Great, thanks! I realize posting an answer with a source can be difficult, but post that as an answer and if everything goes alright with my installation I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issues with this so long as this is not named the same as your existing farm. I've done it on many local development farms that are domain joined.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be an issue. We have 4 diffetent sharepoint farm in same domain. 2 farm sharing same database server as well for developer.

Every sharepoint farm is independent of others.